# create google maps marker from json in ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, google-maps, ionic-framework

i want to make google maps marker from my json: `http://devonder.pe.hu/api/index.php`

i use factory like this

```
.factory('Markers', function($http) {

  var markers = [];

  return {
    getMarkers: function(){

      return $http.get("http://devonder.pe.hu/api/index.php").then(function(response){
          markers = response;
          return markers;
      });

    }
  }
})
```

and my controller like this

```
.controller('mapsctrl', function() {
        var myLatLng = {lat: 1.443306, lng: 125.182833};
    var myLatLng2 ={lat: 1.440444, lng: 125.117778};


      var fasilitas =Markers.getMarkers();



        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 16,
          center: myLatLng
        });

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;
    for( i = 0; i < fasilitas.length; i++ ) {
      var obj=fasilitas[i];
     // var gas[0];
      var judul
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(obj.latitude, obj.longitude);
        //bounds.extend(position);
    //var myLatLngg = {lat: [3][1], lng: [3][2]};
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      map: map,
      title: obj.nama,
      icon: 'img/marker/'+obj.id_kategori +'.png'
        });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                var judul = fasilitas[i]
                infoWindow.setContent('<h5>'+judul.nama+'</h5><b>Alamat: </b>'+judul.alamat+' <br><b>Buka: </b>'+judul.jadwal_praktek+' <br><b>No Telp: </b>'+judul.no_telp+' ');
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));

    } 
    })
```

and it's not work.

Comment: What does not work? Can you provide some working code? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: there is no error, the marker is not appear. the marker data is in the json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using the **Markers** factory without injecting it to your controller

```
app.controller('mapsctrl',['Markers', function(Markers){
    var myLatLng = {lat: 1.443306, lng: 125.182833};
    var myLatLng2 ={lat: 1.440444, lng: 125.117778};
    var fasilitas =Markers.getMarkers();
    --- Rest of your code ---
}]);
```

// or

```
app.controller('mapsctrl',function(Markers){
    var myLatLng = {lat: 1.443306, lng: 125.182833};
    var myLatLng2 ={lat: 1.440444, lng: 125.117778};
    var fasilitas =Markers.getMarkers();
    --- Rest of your code ---
});
```

The controller requests a `$http` and returns the value on success which is a promise so you should use it like this

```
.controller('mapsctrl', function() {
    var myLatLng = {lat: 1.443306, lng: 125.182833};
    var myLatLng2 ={lat: 1.440444, lng: 125.117778};

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 16,
        center: myLatLng
    });


    Markers.getMarkers().then(function(fasilitas){
        // var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        //  zoom: 16,
        //  center: myLatLng
        // });
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i; 
        for( i = 0; i < fasilitas.length; i++ ) {
            var obj=fasilitas[i];
            // var gas[0];
            var judul
            var position = new google.maps.LatLng(obj.latitude, obj.longitude);
            //bounds.extend(position);
            //var myLatLngg = {lat: [3][1], lng: [3][2]};
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: position,
                map: map,
                title: obj.nama,
                icon: 'img/marker/'+obj.id_kategori +'.png'
                // visible : true
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                    var judul = fasilitas[i]
                    infoWindow.setContent('<h5>'+judul.nama+'</h5><b>Alamat: </b>'+judul.alamat+' <br><b>Buka: </b>'+judul.jadwal_praktek+' <br><b>No Telp: </b>'+judul.no_telp+' ');
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));
        } 
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks, i have try this. the maps is appear but the marker is not.

Comment: what values do you get in fasilitas object ? can you provide sample data of fasilitas. also use markers = markers.concat(response); instead of  markers = response;

Comment: i try to passing the json data into fasilitas. so the coordinate, etc will in the fasilitas.